# Processing large files: How to find all space-separated pairs "name:number" and insert a pair "logname:log(number)" right after the matching pair

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have a large file (20G), where each line contains a number of space separated tokens.  For a particular word A, I would like to find all tokens A:number, and insert a new pair logA:log(number) right after the matching token.

Example of input:

```
A:164605 B C D:23 A:223425
```

Desired output:

```
A:164605 logA:5.21 B C D:23 A:223425 logA:5.349
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ( sub(/^A:/,"",$i) )
            $i = sprintf("A:%s logA:%.3f",$i,log($i)/log(10))
    print
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A:164605 logA:5.216 B C D:23 A:223425 logA:5.349
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe 's{\bA:(\d+)\b\K}{sprintf " logA:%.3f", log($1) / log(10)}eg' file.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

One thing that I would consider doing is adding a filter to make sure that the key doesn't already have a `logA` after it using a negative lookahead assertion:

```
s{\bA:(\d+)\b\K(?!\s+logA:)}{...
```